# opencart user login page is redirected to a category page?

Tags: authentication, opencart, opencart-3

We have this problem in our opencart 3.0.2.0 when user enters this url

```
   https://www.ourstore.com/login
```

it goes to a category page, I didn't change any code, we use  Opencart SEO Pack PRO, but I didn't find any connection, I looked in oc_seo_url, I didn't find and row with the value login,

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Its most likely because of that SEO module turn it off and see what happens

Comment: check the path of modification it can be help you "system\storage\modification\catalog\" check if create directory like account/login.php.  if its generate then check the code in loing.php redirect any url.

Comment: yes I disabled the module and it worked correctly thanks every body